# I need help aligning two <li> tags in a top navbar; one to the right and the other in true center

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar, center

The issue I am having is I have a top navigation bar with like 7 li tags and when the screen size is below 720 it goes to just 2 li tags and 6 tags from the full size go into a drop down tab labeled "More". I want to center align the li tag that's not the drop down and right align the drop down li. But if I align the drop down to the right the other element isn't true center, its still effected by the size of the drop down li tag. HALP! haha

Thanks in advance!

In the html the

HI

is for me to see is the "sticky" style is working on scroll haha

But I want the "More" to be aligned to the right of the page and the "Virdian" to be true center of the bar

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

/* BIG SCREENS */
@media only screen and (min-width: 790px) {
.topbar {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
 .nav see {
  display: none;
 }


.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(64,130,109);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(64,130,109);
 }

 /* bar color */
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(55,55,55);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* text color */
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  }

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(64,130,109);
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}


  .nav li {
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin-right: -4px;
 
  }


  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus Hidden*/
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
 }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}

/* SMALL SCREENS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 790px) {



.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(64,130,109);
  border-top: 2px solid rgb(64,130,109);
 }
 
 .nav blink {
  display: none;
 }

 /* bar color */
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: rgb(55,55,55);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* text color */
.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  transition: .3s background-color;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  }

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(64,130,109);
}

  .nav li {
    width: 100px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin-right: -4px;
 
  }


  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus Hidden*/
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: inherit;
 }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<head>
<title>Viridian Computing</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="topbar">
 </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a class="active" href="#">Viridian</a></li>
        <blink><li class="about"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Images</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="#">Holder1</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="#">Holder2</a></li>
  <li class="contact"><a href="#">Services</a></li></blink>
  <see><li class="tutorials"><a href="#">More</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Holder1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Holder2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Holder3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li></see>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
  <p>HI</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't plan on learning to develop professional websites, there is no point in doing your own website: **a)** you will lose more time on it than a professional; **b)** the outcome has more chances of being unprofessional. So, unless you make way less money/hour doing whatever it is you do best, you should hire a professional and just make sure you get back whatever you were promised. Strictly from a management point of view, even web-developers are better off by hiring someone else to do their own website, most times.

Comment: That was really kinda rude. I didn't ask for your opinion on my personal life; just need help with the code. We all start somewhere and if I hire a professional to make my site I will never learn. I am a hardware and network IT administrator by profession and I like to learn new things in my free time.

Comment: I am sorry you found it rude. I was hoping you'd find it helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav > ul {
  position: relative;
}
see {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

... seems to be what you need. It gets `<see>` out of document flow, and positions it absolutely, to the right side, leaving remaining siblings (i.e.:`Viridian`) in parent flow, which is centered.

Comment: Hey thank you. Sorry I got snappy. That worked perfectly!

Comment: You're welcome. Please note `position:absolute` is calculated relative to the closest ancestor with `position:relative`. So, to make sure it stays with the bar, you should also add `.nav ul{position:relative}` to the above.